# UILabel.text returns nil Swift 3

Tags: swift3, uilabel, segue

New to iOS/Swift. I am trying to migrate a project (that simply fetches contents from a URL via the NSData init() method) from Swift 2 to Swift 3 and i am running into couple of issues:

1. I have a `prepareForSegue` in a ViewController. The segue itself works fine, however i am not able to pull the text from the `UILabel` from the origin controller and send it across to the destination controller. For some reason, the destination VC `UIlabel` still shows the default value.
   Segue code:

   ```
   if let identifier = segue.identifier{
               if identifier == "showUserDetailSegue"{
                   if let detailsViewController = segue.destination as? DetailsViewController,
                       let cell = sender as? UserInfoTableViewCell,
                       let text = cell.textLabel?.text{
                       detailsViewController.text = text
                       }  
                   }
           }
   ```

The `detailsViewController.text` is a public var which uses a `didSet` property.

DestinationVC code:

```
    var text: String?{
        didSet{
            updateUI()
        }
    }


private func updateUI(){
        self.detailsTextView.text = text
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBOutlet weak var detailsTextView: UILabel!
```

2.One of my `GET` request URL has some spaces in between. For example if we take a sample URL such as: `http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Game%20of%20Thrones&Season=1`, the async call for this keeps failing with a "URL not valid". Are we supposed to be running some encoding of some sort on this?

Any tips, hints is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any code in place to change the text of the label?

Comment: Yes i do, shall update the question with the destinationVC

Comment: Add debugging statements, is the inside ther complex `if let` even reached?

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?

Answer (score 2):

Is your `UILabel` in `DetailsViewController` an unwrapped optional? Chances are it is still `nil` at that point. The earliest moment you should configure your views is in `viewDidLoad`.

Simply delete the `didSet` handler and set the `UILabel`'s text to `self.text` in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: tried that already..still nothing.. i added the code for the destinationVC

Comment: Have you made sure that the line `detailsViewController.text = text` is actually executed? Maybe one of the definitions in the `if let` statements evaluates to nil.

Comment: It seems like the last if let statement is not returning the text..not sure why...since i can see the list on the screen

Comment: That's because the cell is a custom cell, while you're trying to access the contents of `textLabel`, which is defined in `UITableViewCell`. Or, you called your own outlet `textLabel` which you should **never ever** do in a custom cell.

Comment: That is indeed the cause. Turns out the OS still keeps its default textLabel still in place. A bit different from how Android works. Hence, the confusion for me. Thanks!